# Vaadin 24 SubMenu routing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I'm building a menu bar in Vaadin 24 and got the following to work:

```
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    MenuItem monthlyTasksMenuItem = menuBar.addItem("Monthly Tasks", listener);
    SubMenu monthlyTasksSubMenu = monthlyTasksMenuItem.getSubMenu();
    RouterLink routerLink = new RouterLink( "Select Applicants for Invitations" , AboutView.class );
    monthlyTasksSubMenu.addItem( routerLink );
```

The problem is that the submenu item has the appearance of an anchor tag (i.e. has the underline when you hover over it).  Is there something similar to a RouterLink that just reacts to a mouse click (without the underline)?  Or, is that something I'd have to use CSS to change?

I'm looking for something that works just like routerLink, but without the underline:

```
    <??????> link = new <?????>( "Select Applicants for Invitations" , AboutView.class );
    monthlyTasksSubMenu.addItem( link );
```

Comment: Have you tried calling navigate in a listener

Comment: I have not.  But, I'm hoping to keep the class name as a parameter for the link rather than needing logic in a listener for sorting out what page to navigate to.

Comment: `navigate` accepts a view class